# Отслеживание местоположения в google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Стоит такая задача, нужно хранить историю перемещений конкретного пользователя с последующим отображением его маршрута в google maps. Т.е. админ зашел и посмотрел маршрут данного пользователя в определенный день. Как такое можно реализовать пока понятия не имею.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте на клиенте сервис который будет каждые 5\10\60 минут сохранять координату в базу.
А админ когда заходит координаты подгружаются с базы и отрисовуются у него на карте в виде маршрута (есть API) или точек.